# Argument passed to a Javascript function from a Rails controller results in "undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, controller

I have a simple Telegram bot script that I will be using to crosspost a Post I make on my page to a Telegram channel.

*telegramBot.js*

```
const telegramBot = (message) => {

  console.log(message) # returns undefined

  // request
  const baseUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/"
  const authToken = "hidden"
  const botCommand = "sendMessage"
  const chatId = "hidden"
  var textMessage = message

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/${authToken}/${botCommand}?chat_id=${chatId}&text=${textMessage}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => { console.log(data);
      });
};

export { telegramBot };
```

*And my Posts controller*

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = @user
    if @post.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :js => "telegramBot(#{@post.content});" }
    end
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The function receives a message (`@post.content`) from the `create` action but when I `console.log(message)` I just get `"undefined"` .

How do you correctly pass arguments to a Javascript function from a Rails controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `@post.content` in single quotes

```
format.js { render :js => "telegramBot('#{@post.content}');" }
```

**Why it returns `undefined`?**

Suppose `@post.content = "foo"`

Without single quote it will interpolate `"telegramBot(#{@post.content});"`  as `"telegramBot(foo);"`

If you notice interpolated string `foo` is variable instead of string and as `foo` is not defined anywhere you are getting it as `undefined`

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 Does my answer help you?